# Baby choke when drinking too fast

Tags: newborn, feeding

My new born is too fast in drinking milk from breast and even feeder. The nipple size of feeder is 1, don't know if they make 0. What should I do? He chokes a lot and scares me. He is 2 weeks old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: don't worry! The fact that he chokes is scary, but it also shows that his body reacts to speed of the milk.

My daughter had a similar issue (the milk came to fast for her to handle properly). We used the following tricks to great effect:

- Breastfeeding: use a Nipple shield. This enabled her to latch on and drink comfortably.
- Bottle: we switched to prenatal bottle teat.

Small caveat for the Nipple shield: she became dependant upon it when breastfeeding, so we had to dedicated some time (about a month) to get her off it again. Now she drinks quite happily from the breast.

Comment: ur answer came handy with our second son born 3 weeks ago. I also found that MAM feeders r best as they are anti-colic.

Answer (score 0):

If the baby is coughing, or spluttering, that means they are simply attempting to maintain his/her breathing whilst breastfeeding; they are not in danger.  Suckling and sucking take practice (they are two different mouth motions).  Your kid will figure it out.

Comment: While it is true that choking (coughing/spluttering) results from an attempt to breathe while being nursed, it is incorrect to say that there is no danger; the risk is aspiration. An adult stops drinking and clears the airway. The same should be done for the baby. Eventually, though, they do figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to slow the flow of milk and/or allow the baby to control the flow better, and you can achieve this by playing with the baby's nursing position. First is to use gravity - use breastfeeding positions where the baby is higher than the nipple, like the laid-back/biological nurturing position. To give the baby more control, sit him or her upright on the mom's lap, facing her breast.

I was also told by a breastfeeding consultant that you can reduce the flow by literally holding the blade of your hand firmly on the breast, perpendicular to the nipple.